# Ansible Automation Platform (Tower) API: How to access payload from job launch POST request

Tags: ansible, bitbucket, ansible-automation-platform

I have an Ansible Automation Platform server and I want to launch a job template via webhook from my Bitbucket server. I'm aware that job templates have a [webhook setting](https://docs.ansible.com/automation-controller/latest/html/userguide/job_templates.html#:%7E:text=Currently%20supported%20SCM%20systems%20are%20GitHub%20and%20GitLab), but they currently only support Github or Gitlab. Despite this, I enabled webhooks on the job and tried configuring the webhook URL & secret in Bitbucket to the URL/Key provided on the job, but the connection failed.

As a workaround, I configured the webhook URL on Bitbucket as `https://<ansible host>/api/v2/job_templates/<id>/launch` and it's able to launch the job anytime the webhook fires.

My question is, how do I access the payload that is included in the POST request that Bitbucket sends to Ansible? I'm obviously not able to make Bitbucket include that data under `extra_vars` in the payload, so is there an automatic variable or some other way to access the payload that Bitbucket is providing?

Comment: As far as I understand a playbook job will not have access to such kind of information or on that Automation Platform level, that's why there are `extra_vars`.